# How a company in India can misuse my PAN number and its scanned copy that I provided as an interview candidate?

Tags: income-tax, india, security, fraud, identity-theft

Two companies in Bangalore and Pune (India) asked me to send PAN number (government ID number used as ID for income tax return and transaction, like social security number in the US) and scanned soft copy by email for recruitment purpose in IBM but after sending they said that I was not shortlisted. Now I am worried that is it possible for them to misuse my PAN details and scanned copy for any illegal activity? Should I take any legal action against them?

I read on an advocate's blog that they do this activity to create fake employee profiles or for large illegal or black money transactions because in India you need to have a valid PAN card for large transaction.

I haven't sent scanned copy to them instead of that I sent a picture of PAN card taken from my mobile.

Comment: INDIAN COMPANIES, RECRUITERS THINK THAT THEY CAN DO ANYTHING WITH CANDIDATES.. These Companies HRs INHERITED from PAWN Brokers, so they give PEANUTS but they ask WHOLESOME details..why do they need PAN cards for filtering candidates..?

Answer (score 2):

There is a possibility of misuse. Hence it should be shared judiciously.

Sharing it with large / trusted organization reduces the risk as there would be right process / controls in place.

Broadly these days PAN and other details are shared for quite a few transactions, say applying for a Credit Card, Opening Bank Account, Taking a Phone connection etc. In most of the cases the application is filled out and processed by 3rd party rather than the service provider directly.

Creating Fake Employee records is a possibility so is the misuse to create a fake Bank account in your name and transact in that account.

Since one cannot totally avoid sharing PAN details to multiple parties...

It helps to stay vigilant by monitoring the Form 26AS from the [Govt website](https://nriservices.tdscpc.gov.in/nriapp/login.xhtml). Any large cash transactions / additional salary / or other noteworthy transactions are shown here. It would also help to monitor your [CIBIL reports](https://www.cibil.com/credit-score) that show all the Credit Card and other details under your name.

Comment: Do I need to file any complaint against them.

Comment: @user19083 Only if you have evidence that they have misused. You cannot file complaint for potential misuse. Asking PAN for identification is a valid request.

Comment: Can you please tell me the process to register on the website you mentioned. They are asking TAN number but I am not a tax payee I am a student but I want track my PAN uses.

Comment: @user19083 If you are not a tax payee yet, it would be difficult. Try writing / calling to see if can get access without any tax being deducted. https://nriservices.tdscpc.gov.in/en/contactus.html